# WPF Windows 10 Two Touch Keyboards Visible

Tags: wpf

I have an issue with an existing WPF Application being run on a Windows 10 (experience pack) edition.

Previous Windows build  (ie build 1903) worked as you would expect.  There is no specific code in the App to invoke the keyboard.  The OS displays the keyboard when a TextBox gets focus.  It hides the Keyboard when it loses focus.  This works in both Tablet and Non-Tablet modes.

The problem comes when we run it on say Windows build 20H2.  The issue appeared to be that the keyboard was displayed regardless of TextBox's having focus, but after un-docking the keyboard, it can be seen that there are infact 2 keyboards, the black one is shown/hidden correctly (but infuriatingly does not respond to the InputScope="Number" tag on the TextBox) and the white one is displayed always.

These 2 keyboards are separate from the OSK.exe one controlled from the Ease Of Access Windows Setting

This feels like a bug/issue with their new keyboard in the Experience Pack (which seems related to TextInputHost.exe) being incompatible with their old Keyboard?

Attached is a screen shot with my Test App (button and textbox) and both keyboards visible

[image]

No amount of killing processes/changing windows settings seems to get the OS into a state where one keyboard is visible like it used to.  Is this a WPF/Win 10 incompatibility?  Like when WPF apps used to have to handle the OSK themselves with Events hooked to the Textbox's etc.?  Anyone else even seen 2 keyboards at once?

Thanks

Jay

PS I dont know how to attach images

Comment: I just wanted to provide feedback incase this helps someone.  SO it turned out the double KB was due to us replacing the explorer.exe in order to simulate Kiosk mode.  Our app is WPF on Win 10 Pro we couldn't use the any of the regular Kiosk Mode options.  A year ago when we replaced explorer.exe we found that this also disabled the OSK from working period.  We then updated our app to spawn the explorer.exe process at startup, this proved to work for a few years.  Some update lately has obviously fixed that previous niggle so that there is no need for our app to spawn explorer.exe.

Comment: It did however leave us with the KB that appears correctly, but does not adhere to the Number formatting hint we add to the TextBox XAML.  The only way we found around this was to not replace the shell at all and invoke our app as a regular startup task.  This leaves us with a fully working single keyboard showing the number pad on the number text boxes appearing/disappearing as they gain/lose focus.  The only side effect is the device now appears to a customer as Windows 10 running an app as opposed to a true Kiosk device